# git submodule without placing metadata in separate-git-dir

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to use the old behaviour for submodule metadata.
What command line should I use?

1) clone repository --recursive

2) Add new submodule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to have the submodule repository in the `.git` directory of the submodule's working tree as it used to be stored.  There isn't an option to do that.  If your version of git supports the new method of storing the repository info inside the parent repository, that method will always be used for new submodules.